# Mapbox GL Menu (Layer Switcher) Doesn't Respond to First Click

Tags: mapbox-gl

I'm building a mapbox gl tool showing multiple layers of geojson markers with popup tooltips. My issue is that the menu or layer switcher is unresponsive to the user's first click on each of the menu items. Only after the second click does it function, toggling the layers on and off.

See the issue on my dev site [here](http://development.correctionstocollegeca.com).

Any and all help or points in the right direction are appreacted. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in how you check for the `visibility` property of the layer.
On first click the `visibility` property is `undefined`:

[image]

To fix this, you can explicitly define initial `visibility` on the layers:

```
    map.addLayer({
        "id": "Colleges with campus programs",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "Colleges with prison programs",
        "layout": {
            "visibility": "visible", // <======= add default visibility
            "icon-image": "college-marker",
            "icon-size": 0.5,
            "text-font": ["Open Sans Semibold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
            "text-offset": [0, 0.6],
            "text-anchor": "top"
        },
    });
```

Here is the [related mapbox-gl example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/).

Comment: Beautiful! That worked like a charm. Can't believe I missed it in the example. Thanks so much!.